# Malloc function in C errors with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, binary-tree

I've create this function that's supposed to create a randomly generated binary tree, it works fine but at the end of the function the root == NULL, i can't understand why!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_B 7

typedef struct _ramo{
    int nbanane;
    struct _ramo *dx;
    struct _ramo *sx;
}ramo;

void creaAlbero(ramo *root, int n){
    printf("%d\n",n);
    root = malloc(sizeof(ramo));
    root->nbanane=rand()%MAX_B;
    printf("BANANA! %d\n",root->nbanane);
    root->dx=NULL;
    root->sx=NULL;
    if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
        creaAlbero(root->dx, n+1);
    if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
        creaAlbero(root->sx, n+1);
 }

int main(){
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    ramo *root=NULL;
    creaAlbero(root, 1);
    if (root==NULL) {
        printf("EMPTY!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is pass by value, you need a pointer to a pointer parameter in `creaAlbero` to modify your `root` object in `main`.

Comment: the code needs to check the returned value from a call to malloc to assure successful operation

Comment: the function: 'creaAlbero' could recurse forever if the result of "if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)"  was never 0

Comment: @user3629249 that's true before i've had a limitation but i've noticed that it's pretty rare to get "n" over 5 so i've take it off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `root` to `NULL`:

```
ramo *root=NULL;
```

then pass a copy of it to `creaAlbero()`:

```
creaAlbero(root, 1);
```

which modifies the copy

```
root = malloc(sizeof(ramo));
```

then returns. The original `root` is still `NULL`, because nothing changed it.

Consider returning `root` from `creaAlbero()`:

```
ramo * creaAlbero(int n){
  printf("%d\n",n);

  ramo *root = malloc(sizeof(ramo));
  root->nbanane=rand()%MAX_B;
  printf("BANANA! %d\n",root->nbanane);
  root->dx=NULL;
  root->sx=NULL;

  if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
    root->dx = creaAlbero(n+1);
  if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
    root->sx = creaAlbero(n+1);

  return root;
}

int main(){
  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
  ramo *root=NULL;
  root = creaAlbero(1);
  if (root==NULL) {
    printf("EMPTY!!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Example: https://ideone.com/dXiv8A

Answer (score 2):

`creaAlbero(ramo *root, int n)` is a function that takes a copy of a pointer to a `ramo`.  It then proceeds to do stuff with this copy of the pointer, and then returns.  `main` then looks a the value of the *origonal* `root` variable, which was (obviously) never changed.

If you want a function to modify a value that's passed in, you must pass the object by pointer.  To clarify: if you want a function to modify a pointer, the function must take as a parameter a pointer *to a pointer* to a thing:

```
void creaAlbero(ramo **rootptr, int n){     //pass rootptr by pointer     
    *rootptr = malloc(sizeof(ramo)); //modify pointer pointed at by rootptr
    ramo* root = *rootptr; //make local copy of value for ease of use
    //rest of your code here
}
int main(){
    ramo *root=NULL;
    creaAlbero(&root, 1);  //pass by pointer
```

[Paul Roub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27972591/845092) also suggests another excellent idea: return the `ramo*` from the function instead of taking it as a mutable parameter.  It's simpler and more intuitive by far.

Answer (score 1):

`root` is passed to `creaAlbero` by value. Any changes made to `root` in `creaAlbero` are only local modifications. They don't change the value of `root` in main. A better alternative would be to change the signature of `creaAlbero` to:

```
ramo* creaAlbero(int n){
   printf("%d\n",n);
   ramo* root = malloc(sizeof(ramo));
   root->nbanane=rand()%MAX_B;
   printf("BANANA! %d\n",root->nbanane);
   root->dx=NULL;
   root->sx=NULL;
   if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
      root->dx = creaAlbero(n+1);
   if ((int)(rand()%n)==0)
      root->sx = creaAlbero(n+1);

   return root;
}
```

and change the usage to:

```
int main(){
   srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
   ramo *root = creaAlbero(1);
   if (root==NULL) {
      printf("EMPTY!!");
   }
   return 0;
}
```